# BlocBuilder builder function gets called only once

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

Good evening, I have been working with bloc pattern and I have some issues: The state update is being called only once on BlocBuilder, no matter what I do

What I have as state is:

```dart
class DateScreenState {
  Future<List<PrimaryPetModifierModel>> primaryPetModifiers;
  Future<List<SecondaryPetModifierModel>> secondaryPetModifiers;

  PrimaryPetModifierModel primaryPetModifierSelected;
  SecondaryPetModifierModel secondaryPetModifierSelected;

  Widget animatedWidget;

  DateTime dateOfSchedule;
  DateTime timeOfSchedule;

  bool shouldReload = false;
  bool isFirstCallAnimation = true;
}
```

And my mapEventToState looks like this:

```dart
@override
  Stream<DateScreenState> mapEventToState(
      ScheduleDateScreenEvent event) async* {
    if (event is SelectPrimaryModifierEvent) {
      state.primaryPetModifierSelected = event.modifier;
      yield state;
    } else if (event is SelectSecondaryModifierEvent) {
      state.secondaryPetModifierSelected = event.modifier;
      yield state;
    }
  }
```

My exact issue is, when I change a value in a DropdownButton, it will fire a SelectedPrimaryModifierEvent or SelectedSecondaryModifier event, the event firing works fine, but the state yielding and updating will happen only **once** after the first fire of any of those events, after that, BlocBuilder builder function will not be called anymore after any event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're yielding the same state with each event, despite the fact that you're changing a variable with the `DateScreenState` class. Try splitting up your primary and secondary into different state classes and yield them separately in your `mapEventToState`.

Comment: Like a deep clone or something?

Comment: It wouldn't be a clone. With what you shared I don't really know everything that's going on with your bloc, but it appears you could have a separate state defined for primary, and another one for secondary. If you share your full Bloc/Event/State code I can have a look.

Comment: After understanding what you said, I could solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Great, no problem.